# Merging Pandas dataframes without overwriting columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes into a larger dataframe, both with a common column and a new column. Lets say the main dataframe looks like this:

```
 Main_DF:
VID  RID   Host  Ref

V-1  R-as5   OS-1   Blah
V-2  R-b8i   OS-2   Blah
V-4  R-96s   OS-4   Blah
V-8  R-2bv   OS-a   Blah
```

I have 2 dataframes that look like this

```
    DF2:
VID Source
V-1   E
V-4   G
V-8   T
```

```
   DF3:
RID  Source
R-b8i   H
```

I would like to merge both data frames in so the result looks like this:

```
 Main_DF:
VID  RID   Host  Ref  Source

V-1  R-as5   OS-1   Blah  E
V-2  R-b8i   OS-2   Blah  H
V-4  R-96s   OS-4   Blah  G
V-8  R-2bv   OS-a   Blah  T
```

Currently, when I try to perform a left join with both dataframes, one at a time, the last dataframe I merge overwrites the data of the previous dataframe.
I've tried simply doing `Main_DF`*`=`*`Main_DF.merge(Main_DF,DF2,on="VID",how="left").fillna(0)` and `Main_DF`*`=`*`Main_DF.merge(Main_DF,DF3,on="RID",how="left").fillna(0)` but have had no success with this. I have also tried merging both in with a single statement Main _DF.merge() but this hasn't worked either in my experience.  Any suggestions for how I can go about doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
main_DF["Source"] = main_DF.merge(DF2, on = "VID", how = "outer")\
                    .merge(DF3, on = "RID", how = "outer")\
                    .filter(like = "Source")\
                    .replace(float(nan), "")\
                    .sum(axis = 1)
```

Documentation:

1. [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
2. [`pandas.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)
3. [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
Main_DF.merge(DF2, how='left').combine_first(Main_DF.merge(DF3, how='left'))
```

If you have more than two DataFrames:

```
from functools import reduce

out = reduce(lambda a, b: a.combine_first(b),
             [Main_DF.merge(other, how='left')
              for other in [DF2, DF3]]) # add dataframes to merge here
```

Output:

```
   VID    RID  Host   Ref Source
0  V-1  R-as5  OS-1  Blah      E
1  V-2  R-b8i  OS-2  Blah      H
2  V-4  R-96s  OS-4  Blah      G
3  V-8  R-2bv  OS-a  Blah      T
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which works for any arbitrary list of dataframes:

```
list_dfs = [DF2, DF3]
pd.concat(
    [Main_DF.loc[Main_DF[y.index[0]] == y[0],:].assign(Source=y[1]) 
     for x in list_dfs for _,y in x.iterrows()])
```

Output:

```
   VID    RID  Host   Ref Source
0  V-1  R-as5  OS-1  Blah      E
2  V-4  R-96s  OS-4  Blah      G
3  V-8  R-2bv  OS-a  Blah      T
1  V-2  R-b8i  OS-2  Blah      H
```